# Handling multiple messages in message queue

Tags: ipc, mqueue

I've done some research about this topic but I didn't understand it quite well.

From `msgsnd man page` :

> The msgsnd() system call appends a copy of the message pointed to by
>          msgp to the message queue whose identifier is specified by msqid.

Does this mean that when i use a `msgget` to create a message queue the Enqueue and Dequeue happens automatically with `msgsnd` and `msgrcv`?

For example, if I want to use a message queue that can simultaneously hold N messages, when i use `msgsnd` i put a message to the queue and when i use `msg rcv` i get it from here and delete that message?

If that's the case i shouldn't implement manually enqueue and dequeue to create a list of N messages because it's enough to set a value to `const void *msgp` from        `int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);` to add one more message in the queue and it is enough that this is received by `msgrcv` to be deleted from the queue otherwise it remains in the queue until it is received by some process, am i correct?

But then how much messages this queue can contain if i'm not the one setting how many can be contained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [man2(msgrcv)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv) enqueue/dequeue operations are handled internally by  systemV API. so you don't need to re-implement them just use the provided API.

For message queue attributes use [msgctl](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgctl) with IPC_INFO command.